# How to display a special message if a filtered list view contains no results any more?

Tags: android, listview

Is there any way to show a message such as "No results" when i filter a list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy. Next to your list view, add this text view:

```
<TextView android:id="@id/android:empty"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:text="@string/empty_list_message"/>
```

The ID is important; the ListActivity will look for it.

Emmanuel