# How to display "No Result" in filterable ListView?

Tags: android, android-listview, filtering, android-edittext, textwatcher

I have a `ListView` and an `EditText`. I implement `addTextChangedListener` on `EditText` to **filter** the `ListView` content.

```
leftList.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
et_search.addTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);
```

and then the `TextWatcher` is:

```
private TextWatcher filterTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
            int count) {

         if (watcherAdapter==null) {
             return;
         }

         watcherAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);

         Log.e(TAG, "OnTextChange: " + s + " start: " + start +
         " before: " + before + " count: " + count + " adapter: " +
         watcherAdapter.getCount());    

    }
};
```

Condition:

1. I have 10 items in `ListView`.

Question:

1. When I first type the first character, why the `watcherAdapter.getCount()` returns `10` (as initial) in `ListVie`w instead of the returned filter result count? The `watcherAdapter.getCount(`) seems a-click late for the displayed result in `ListView`.
2. How I achieve to show `"No Result"` in `ListView` when there is no match results as I type on the `EditText`?

Comment: The only solution I use at last is to do my custom search filter....Split the words, tokenizes them, and if matched put it on array as adapter to the List. And it works as I want it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I use at last is to do my custom search filter....Split the words, tokenizes them, and if matched put it on array as adapter to the List. And it works as I want it

Answer (score 3):

It's cleaner to add a TextView to your layout, above or bellow the list, where you show the message:

```
<TextView 
android:id="@+id/noResultsFoundView" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="No result"
android:visibility="gone"
/>
```

When you have results, you set the visibility to GONE. When you have no results you set it to VISIBLE.

To listen for this you could implement a custom filter or at least override the method

```
publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results)
```

from the Filter, where the correct, updated count is passed in FilterResults parameter.

In publishResults you call a method from the activity to update the visibility of noResultsFoundView. How you access the activity depends of where your filter is. If it's in an inner class of the activity then it's easy. Otherwise you for example pass the activity as parameter to instantiate the adapter, and store it as intance variable.

Answer (score 2):

**Of course it is possible to show no result in filterable list. Please refere the below code**

```
 @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.home, menu);

        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search);
        final AppCompatEditText searchView = (AppCompatEditText) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
        if (searchView != null) {
            searchView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                          int arg3) {
                    if(mAdapter==null)
                        return;
                        mAdapter.getFilter().filter(arg0.toString());
                        if(mAdapter.getItemCount()<1){
                            listView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            txtEmptyList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }else{
                            listView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            txtEmptyList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                                              int arg2, int arg3) {
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {

                }
            });
        }
        MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(searchItem, this);
        MenuItemCompat.setActionView(searchItem, searchView);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(!fillMaps.isEmpty())
            {
            SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    WorldClockActivity.this, fillMaps, R.layout.grid_item,
                    from, to);
            lv1.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
            else
            {      String[] emptyList = new String[] {"No record found"};
            lv1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(WorldClockActivity.this,R.layout.list_item, emptyList));
            }
```

You should use two adapter for doing this in the above code i have use two adapter first one is set when we found item in the map if map is empty then you should add another adapter i have put it in else condition.I have done it and it is running fine.
I hope you got your solution.

Comment: Dont really get it. You put this onTextChanged? I suppose fillMaps in your case is also a click late right?

Answer (score 0):

Simpler and cleaner that other answers: take a look at `ListActivity`'s empty `View`:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html

See also:

[How to display a special message if a filtered list view contains no results any more?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378940/how-to-display-a-special-message-if-a-filtered-list-view-contains-no-results-any)

[Android: set empty view to a list view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15949839/android-set-empty-view-to-a-list-view)

[Showing empty view when ListView is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3771568/showing-empty-view-when-listview-is-empty)