# Alert Dialog when text not found in ListView

Tags: android, listview, filter, android-alertdialog

How can I show an `AlertDialog` stating that there is no available item on the list?

I have an `EditText` where I can input some text and will result to automatic filter of the items in `ListView` according to the text I input.

here is my code:

```
searchUniv = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtUnivNameSearch);
searchUniv.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ((Filterable) UnivAll.this.adapter1).getFilter().filter(s);

        }


    });
```

Thanks for the answer! I am new in Android Development, and I hope that you can help me.

Comment: Do you **need* to show an `AlertDialog` for this? Typically, using an [Empty List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15949839/android-set-empty-view-to-a-list-view) in your `ListView` would be more appropriate and less intrusive

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
if(s.length() == 0) {
       //show Dialog   
}
```

in the `onTextChanged` function

```
ListView list;
if(list.getChildCount() == 0) {
   //Show dialog
}
```

Comment: The alert dialog was shown when the EditText is empty instead of showing when there is no items on the list. I want to show the Alert Dialog when there are no items on list. @TDMaster