# It's possible to add ImageView programatically on ListFragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-listfragment

In my project, I have a `Fragment` that is a `ListFragment`. What I have done so far is filling the List with data from a `SQLite` database; but now, I am facing this problem:

***If I've no data in the database, my `ListFragment` will be empty; that's why I thought to put an Image, in place of list.***

Now, I am stuck on how to use `onCreateView` in my `ListFragment`.

*One alternative to this, that I found is: "using `Fragment` instead of `ListFragment`"*

*Is there any other way to do this, without replacing `ListFragment` with `Fragment`?*

### EDIT 1

This goes inside of `doInBackGround`:

```
Conexion = new MarketSQLite(getActivity(), "market", null, 1);
mItems = new ArrayList<ListViewItem>();
db = Conexion.getReadableDatabase();

Cursor c;
c = db.rawQuery("Select NOM_OFER,PREU_OFERTA,DATA_F,FOTO,PERCENTDESCOMPTE from T_OFERTA", null);
c.moveToFirst();
// HERE'S NOT NULL, SO I CAN PUT SOME STUFF
if (c != null) {
    do {
        for (int i = 0; i < c.getColumnCount(); i++) {
            Title = c.getString((c.getColumnIndex("NOM_OFER")));
            Preu = c.getColumnIndex("PREU_OFERTA");
            percent = c.getString((c.getColumnIndex("PERCENTDESCOMPTE")));
            data_f = c.getString((c.getColumnIndex("DATA_F")));
            URLTest = c.getString((c.getColumnIndex("FOTO")));
            Log.e("", "" + c.getString(i));

            // initialize and set the list adapter
            // Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Title" + Title + "Preu" + Preu + "Percent" + percent + "Cheese is " + data_f, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        mItems.add(new ListViewItem(URLTest, Title, Preu.toString(), percent, data_f));
    } while (c.moveToNext());
}

if (c== null) {
    getListView().setEmptyView(getActivity().findViewById(R.id.layout_empty));
    // HERE I WANT TO ADD IMAGEVIEW CAUSE C IS NULL THEN THE FRAGMENT WON'T BE EMPTY
}
c.close();
```

And this is the error what I'm facing :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
    at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:426)
    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
    at info.androidhive.slidingmenu.MisOfertasFragment$MyAsyncTask.doInBackground(MisOfertasFragment.java:108)
    at info.androidhive.slidingmenu.MisOfertasFragment$MyAsyncTask.doInBackground(MisOfertasFragment.java:86)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

### EDIT 2

*I made some changes with the cursor. I deleted some data on my `SQLite` to test if it works; but now, it doesn't show anything.*

```
Cursor c;
c = db.rawQuery("Select NOM_OFER,PREU_OFERTA,DATA_F,FOTO,PERCENTDESCOMPTE from T_OFERTA", null);

//HERE'S NOT NULL, SO I CAN PUT SOME STUFF
if (c.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        for (int i = 0; i < c.getColumnCount(); i++) {
            Title = c.getString((c.getColumnIndex("NOM_OFER")));
            Preu = c.getColumnIndex("PREU_OFERTA");
            percent = c.getString((c.getColumnIndex("PERCENTDESCOMPTE")));
            data_f = c.getString((c.getColumnIndex("DATA_F")));
            URLTest = c.getString((c.getColumnIndex("FOTO")));
            Log.e("", "" + c.getString(i));

            // initialize and set the list adapter
            // Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Title" + Title + "Preu" + Preu + "Percent" + percent + "Cheese is " + data_f, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        mItems.add(new ListViewItem(URLTest, Title, Preu.toString(), percent, data_f));
    } while (c.isAfterLast());
}

if (!c.moveToFirst()) {
    Log.d("No registres","pewpew");

    // HERE I WANT TO ADD IMAGEVIEW CAUSE C IS NULL THEN THE FRAGMENT WON'T BE EMPTY
}
c.close();
```

Comment: You want an image to be displayed in place of your list if it is empty?

Comment: No, I want to display an Image on the center if my list it's empty

Comment: For that you need to add emptyview to your ListFragment Listview

Comment: Thats a too simple.  Just add a EmptyView for your listview

Comment: Where I've to add EmptyView on xml?

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15949839/android-set-empty-view-to-a-list-view

Comment: @Skizo have you got the solution??

Comment: @kalyanpvs Not yet :( I've implemented Bhavdip Pathar answer but it doesn't work or I'm doing something wrong :S

Comment: @Skizo still not get solution?? can i need to add my answer??

Comment: @kalyanpvs I didn't find the solution, at the moment I just put a AlertDialog... but If you can help me out, would be nice too, the thing is the part that I need next, with my Alertdialog I made a button that goes to another Fragment, but this fragment is never closed, wich means that If I go thourgh another fragment it still the data behind the new fragment... But yes, if you can help me out with this first problem would be gratefull (BTW, I'm not using a ListView)

Comment: @skizo not sure, but I guess you need c.getCount() instead of c.getColumnCount(). Even, I guess, you don't need the for loop, the while loop will do all for you. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing

```
Cursor c;
c = db.rawQuery("Select NOM_OFER,PREU_OFERTA,DATA_F,FOTO,PERCENTDESCOMPTE from T_OFERTA", null);

//HERE'S NOT NULL, SO I CAN PUT SOME STUFF
if (c.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        for (int i = 0; i < c.getColumnCount(); i++) {
            Title = c.getString((c.getColumnIndex("NOM_OFER")));
            Preu = c.getColumnIndex("PREU_OFERTA");
            percent = c.getString((c.getColumnIndex("PERCENTDESCOMPTE")));
            data_f = c.getString((c.getColumnIndex("DATA_F")));
            URLTest = c.getString((c.getColumnIndex("FOTO")));
            Log.e("", "" + c.getString(i));

            // initialize and set the list adapter
            // Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Title" + Title + "Preu" + Preu + "Percent" + percent + "Cheese is " + data_f, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        mItems.add(new ListViewItem(URLTest, Title, Preu.toString(), percent, data_f));
    } while (c.isAfterLast());
}

if (!c.moveToFirst()) {
    Log.d("No registres","pewpew");

    // HERE I WANT TO ADD IMAGEVIEW CAUSE C IS NULL THEN THE FRAGMENT WON'T BE EMPTY
}
c.close();
```

To

```
Cursor c;
c = db.rawQuery("Select NOM_OFER,PREU_OFERTA,DATA_F,FOTO,PERCENTDESCOMPTE from T_OFERTA", null);

//HERE'S NOT NULL, SO I CAN PUT SOME STUFF
if (c.moveToFirst()) {
    do {

            Title = c.getString((c.getColumnIndex("NOM_OFER")));
            Preu = c.getColumnIndex("PREU_OFERTA");
            percent = c.getString((c.getColumnIndex("PERCENTDESCOMPTE")));
            data_f = c.getString((c.getColumnIndex("DATA_F")));
            URLTest = c.getString((c.getColumnIndex("FOTO")));


        mItems.add(new ListViewItem(URLTest, Title, Preu.toString(), percent, data_f));
    } while (c.moveToNext());
}

if (!c.moveToFirst()) {
    Log.d("No registres","pewpew");

    // HERE I WANT TO ADD IMAGEVIEW CAUSE C IS NULL THEN THE FRAGMENT WON'T BE EMPTY
}
c.close();
```

and put this -

```
getListView().setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.layout_empty));
```

before calling setListAdapter.

Lets see, if that works.

Comment: But it won't show an Image :(... The bucle that I made to put the ListItem it works, as I said it doesn't work when I've no data on my SQLite it doesn't show nothing, just a blankFragment

Comment: Isn't putting -"getListView().setEmptyView(getActivity().findViewById(R.id.layout_empty));" before setListAdapter working?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly - you can make your layout look like this. ImageView with such id will be displayed at the center of your page if listview is empty

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:dividerHeight="1px"
        android:paddingLeft="3dp"
        android:paddingRight="3dp">
    </ListView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@android:id/empty"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
<!-- Maybe some your stuff here --> 
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi If you extends the list fragment and want to set the image view when the list view is empty. android provide set empty view method for display the view when the list view has not data available.see below how to set the empty view.

Below is the layout of my list fragment the layout content the empty layout of image view that will display when the list view has not content to display. actually it always hide behind the list view.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:paddingLeft="8dp"
         android:paddingRight="8dp">

     <ListView 
           android:id="@id/android:list"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:background="#00FF00"/>

      <include layout="@android:layout/empty_content" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

empty_content.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/layout_empty"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_gravity="center" >

  <ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_app_logo" />

</LinearLayout>
```

In you java code open you list fragment, add the below line in your fragment.

```
getListView().setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.layout_empty));
```

Comment: I did it, but when I lauch it only shows the image inside the ItemList, I want to show it on the center no inside of the ListItem

Comment: If the empty view is showing even if your list view have data then simply set visibility gone in you layout. list view it self make it visible when the list view have not data to display.

Comment: I'm testing it wait :D

Comment: My solution will work in both case either if you extends ListFramgnet or Normal Fragment. if you extends the normal Fragment then you have to define empty using the object of list view such like  mListiew.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.layout_empty)); other wise getListView() is available when you extends the ListFragment.

Comment: I think the thing that I'm doing wrong is at the time I check my cursor, let me edit my question with some code

Comment: It is another issue i think it is not related to the empty view. let me check

Comment: Hi can you debug the code, exception shown that the cursor index out of bound you try to access the index in cursor that are not available.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75514/discussion-between-skizo-and-bhavdip-pathar).

Comment: Can you come to chat? we should avoid extended discussions in comments